# Remove linkage to libs in qmake

Tags: qt, qmake

I have qmake `.pro` file with dependency from webkit (QT += webkit). When `qmake` is executed and Makefile is generated, I see that it's linking to some additional libs, which was not connected explicitly in `.pro` file.

I would like to use newer version of some lib, and remove linkage to older version.

I have tried te following things:

1. Delete the Makefile
2. Add `"LIBS -= -llibrary_name"` in the end of `.pro` file
3. Generate Makefile with qmake but it does not work - linkage to older
   version of lib is still present in Makefile.

Is it possible to remove linkage in current case?

Comment: Is the linked library a webkit dependency?

Comment: It's a webkitwidgets dependency - If I'll remove "QT += webkitwidgets" in .pro file, linkege to those libs will not be present in generated makefile

Comment: @buggi-zhuk webkitwidgets already depends on specific version of a library. If you want to update it, you'll have to rebuild webkitwidgets.

Comment: I think you'd actually need to change the qmake of webkitwidgets in this case, you can't just change the library in your top qmake. That is if webkitwidgets is actually compatible with the version you want. I am not sure why you want to do this in the first place. What is the use case?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to recompile your version of Qt to use the libraries you want. The information comes from the build configuration of the Qt version that you're using. Simply point Qt's `configure` to the relevant libraries you wish to override, build it, and use it to build your project. It will automatically pull in the newer libraries that you overrode.